# Arrows for list view in Android

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way where I can have default arrows in a list view,without reading them as an array from the xml? If I use ImageViews for arrows,then they might become really ugly. I am bad in graphic design.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I found this site that could be useful to many people.

[material design icons](https://materialdesignicons.com)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by arrows in a ListView...

Comment: Arrows in each row of a listview i mean. It is a way for the user to understand that a new screen will appear.

Comment: In that case do put an image of an arrow in your drawable folders (for all the different sizes). Like someone below said, the icon pack provided by Google is a good way to start, I get most of my icons from there. Otherwise you can just put a textview and use the ">" symbol. Not sure how that would look, but could work well, even if looking slightly iOSy.

Comment: iOS has it by default in the UITable. But Android is cool. Not as good as iOS,but google documentations are pretty cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use this Unicode codes to *draw* arrows as text (if that is what you want)

- `U+2192` →
- `U+25B6` ▶
- `U+2794` ➔

More codes here: http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom layout to make the arrow as a part of the background of the list view row, [look here](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/twitter/5/listview-custom-adapter-example)

you will be able to do something like this:

[image: embedded image]

Just follow the instructions

Answer (score 1):

If you are bad at graphic design you can use free resources from net instead.

Here you have the Google free icon resources you can use with material style where you can find some arrows

[Google icon pack](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this for android icons for different uses https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/. You can use it for your list item row. If you want arrow like ios then create row ui and take imageview for arrow.

Row XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Your Text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" >

    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```